# How to select all records in one table where no records in second table based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with subdivisions:

```
id
subcondoname
```

I have a second table that has real estate listings that looks like this:

```
SubdivisionID (this ties back to id on the subdivision table)
inactive
status
```

I want a query that pulls every `subcondoname` from the first table where there is no record in the second with `inactive = 0` or `status = active`

Comment: Are you looking for [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/left-join.php) ? Can you please add some sample data and expected output to help you.

Comment: More or less duplicated question [MySQL not exists in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+not+exists+in+other+table)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `NOT EXISTS` would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.subdivisionid = t1.id AND (t2.inactive = 0 OR t2.status = 'active')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above two answers,

`NOT EXISTS` will run bit faster as compare to `LEFT JOIN`. Because `LEFT JOIN` reads data from both the table i.e. scanning  and than compares them as per the given logic
whereas `NOT EXISTS` simply do ANTI SEMI JOIN which partially fetches result from Subdivision table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below

SELECT * FROM subdivision s
LEFT JOIN realstate r on s.id = r.subdivisionid
WHERE Isnull(r.inactive,0) = 0 OR r.status = 'active'

Answer (score 0):

You have get some idea from following link.

https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/find-empty-tables-in-database